# JSON Array Structure Variations

Tags: json

Below are 3 JSON Array structure formats...

The first one, the one outlined at JSON.org, is the one I am familiar with:

**Format #1**

```
{"People": [
  {
    "name": "Sally",
    "age": "10"
  },
  {
    "name": "Greg",
    "age": "10"
  }
]}
```

The second one is a slight variation that names the elements of the array.  I personally don't care for it; you don't name elements of an array in code (they are accessed by index), why name them in JSON?

**Format #2**

```
{"People": [
  "Person1": {
    "name": "Sally",
    "age": "10"
  },
  "Person2": {
    "name": "Greg",
    "age": "10"
  }
]}
```

This last one is another variation, quite similar to **Format #2**, but I have a hunch this one is incorrect because it appears to have extra curly braces where they do not belong.

**Format #3**

```
{"People": [
  {
    "Person1": {
      "name": "Sally",
      "age": "10"
    }
  },
  {
    "Person2": {
      "name": "Greg",
      "age": "10"
    }
  }
]}
```

Again, I'm confident that **Format #1** is valid as it is the JSON Array format outlined at JSON.org.  However, what about **Format #2** and **Format #3**?  Are either of those considered valid JSON?  If yes, where did those formats come from?  I do not see them outlined at JSON.org or on Wikipedia.

Comment: Actually, they're all invalid: http://jsonlint.com/

Comment: Oops, I'm missing some punctuation... fixing.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Both #1 and #3 are (nearly - there are commas missing) valid JSON, but encode different structures:

- #1 gives you an **Array** of **Objects**, each with name and age **String properties**
- #3 gives you an **Array** of **Objects**, each with a single **Object property**, each with name and age **String properties**.

The #2 is invalid: Arrays (as defined by `[` ... `]`) may not contain property names.

Answer (score 1):

Solution For **Format#1**
By default:

```
array=[];
object={};
```

JSON Code:

```
var Json = {
    People:[]
};
Json.People.push({
     "name": "Sally",
     "age": "10"                        
});
Json.People.push({
     "name": "Greg",
     "age": "10"                        
});
```

JSON Result:

`{"People": 
    [
      {
        "name": "Sally",
        "age": "10"
      },
      {
        "name": "Greg",
        "age": "10"
      }
    ]
}`