# Taking data from json array

Tags: php, json, laravel

This is my json array.

```
{"Project": [
 {
"name": "Project1",
"category": "Web",
"total_maintenance": "0",
"maintenance_start": "2021-11-01",
"maintenance_end": "2021-11-10",
"email": "test12323@test.com",
 },
{
"name": "Project1",
"category": "Mobile",
"total_maintenance": "0",
"maintenance_start": "2021-11-01",
"maintenance_end": "2021-11-10",
"email": "test12323@test.com",
},
]}
```

I want to be able to use 1 variable like Project[0]->name but i dont know how to. This is in my laravel function.

```
public function store(Request $request)
{
    // request()->validate([
    //     'name' => 'required',
    //     'category' => 'required',
    //     'total_maintenance' => 'required',
    //     'maintenance_start' => 'required',
    //     'maintenance_end' => 'required',
    //     'email'=> 'required',
    // ]);




    // \Log::info($request->getContent());

    $projects = $request->getContent();

    Log::info(var_dump(json_decode($request->getContent())->Project[0]->name));
}
```

I commented out the `request()->validate` because it keeps returning error saying the field is required if i use the json body above. That only worked for my postman is i use the params way. Anyway I tried `Log::info(var_dump(json_decode($request->getContent())->Project[0]->name));` but i got the

> Trying to get property 'Project' of non-object error.

I also tried `$request->all()` but another error too.

Comment: fyi, that's invalid JSON

Comment: @hassan  i got the array format from here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14130245/json-array-structure-variations

Comment: https://jsonformatter.curiousconcept.com/# check your format from here. Then you can json_decode and take varible

Comment: @HasanÇetin Thank you i have updated my post after using the checker

Comment: fyi, that _still_ is invalid JSON!

Comment: @brombeer can i know where's the mistake? i checked using the formatter it returns with valid result

Comment: That JSON doesn't return with a valid result or you copied the wrong result ... the result returned says "_Removed trailing comma._" for your "email" fields and that last `},`

Comment: It seems to work for me https://snipit.io/public/snippets/60011 I suppose that the data is not being received